# http request taking too much time in app but less in website

Tags: angularjs, cordova, nginx, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I have a website and an app which is just an iframe running that website. But the request in the app are taking much time compared to the same request in the website.

Below are the HAR request for the app and the website, as you can see the requests are same but the time taken by the same requests are different.

1. [Cordova App HAR](http://cdn.storehippo.com/s/576253cbd08b24115d6731e6/ms.files/Cordovaapp.har)
2. [Website HAR](http://cdn.storehippo.com/s/576253cbd08b24115d6731e6/ms.files/website.har)

Comment: Use a mobile device, test both of your links and you will see, that the loading time is the same. The problem is, that you are loading to much data into the RAM. Try to separat the task in multiple tasks.